# Drag and drop feature of the custom tags in DocuSign to my web application using C#?

Tags: c#, .net-core, docusignapi, draggable

I am posting this question after searching a lot on stack over flow , but did not find any answer.

I want to drag and drop custom fields onto my PDF/Docx files, so that when I send this document to recipient, he/she sees pre populated information.

**Why am I doing this?**
because I don't want to use Embedded Sending feature via API, because it shows:

1.Standard Fields
2.Other Fields
3.It shows DocuSign look and feel as well

for better clarification , I am attaching the image as well
[image: r]

If you see above image, it has only draggable custom fields which are populated from DocuSign, but this whole user experience is inside a web application , not navigating to DocuSign console

Even if we have to DocuSign Embedded Sending, how can I show only :

1.My own created custom fields and SignHere tags
2.How can I hide other buttons from DocuSign like Save & Close, because if I do that, my changes will not be saved on templates

FYI, there are few applications already doing this.

Comment: Welcome! ***Please check (accept) the best answer to your question. Many thanks!!***

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you want to create a drag and drop use experience for the **sender** and then send the signing request to one or more **signers** yes?

You don't want to use the DocuSign embedded **sending** UX.

Answer: no problem, just a small matter of programming!

What I'd do:

- Create a graphical drag n drop app for tagging your docs with your data items
- Your app's "toolbar" would also need the fields (tabs) that your use case needs for signing. Eg a `sign here` tab, and maybe other tabs such as `date signed`, `initial here` etc.
- The output of your "tagger app" could be a PDF Form or HTML. In either case, you'll need to include the tags and their meta data in the output file.
- Create a DocuSign API app that uses the DocuSign eSignature REST API to upload the output file and transform the tag data into DocuSign tags.
- Send the envelope.

### An easier solution

The above is certainly do-able but will be a lot of work.

An easier solution:

- Use the DocuSign branding feature to update the Sending UX to better match your brand.
- Use the DocuSign [custom fields](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-custom-fields) feature to add custom fields (draggable tab types) for each of your specific data types. Eg Agency Address, Agency ACN, etc. In each of those tab types, set the Data Label attribute. Later, your app will use the Data Label to locate the tabs.
- The sender uses an embedded sender view to create the envelope
- Before the envelope is actually sent, your app reads the draft envelope and lists the envelope's tabs. Then match the API's `tabLabel` attribute with the previously set `Data Label` attribute (they're the same thing). Set the tab values accordingly.
- Then send the envelope.

### Re changing the embedded signing controls

Yes, this is doable. See this [blog post](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/introducing-customizable-embedded-sending)

If you want further customization of the embedded sending view make a suggestion via https://feedback.docusign.com and then follow up via your DocuSign account manager.

### Added: examples of building a custom tagger?

I don't know of any open source document taggers. Building one is hard. DocuSign has many engineers dedicated to the DocuSign web app.

As the OP mentions in his comment, an alternative idea is to create a "tiny language" that document creators can then add to their documents. This can be done, but it is more difficult for document creators than a WYSIWYG drag and drop UX.

A more common business process flow is to carefully analyze the documents and then create standardized documents and document sets.

That way the sender does not need to use a tagger. Instead, they select from a list or fill in a form. The app then creates the document that is needed, complete with data fields pulled from other apps.

The [DocuSign CLM product](https://www.docusign.com/products/clm) is designed for this type of use case.

Comment: larry-k  Last two options i have already used, but there are so many challenges like , I don't want any users to play around docusign embedded sending console side. even I have referred to Alan Roza's blog to hide all buttons, but still I see Save & Close and Discard button and other unwanted tags section[like standard, payment fields] which was not needed for me, so I will not use the same approach again but looking into your first solution do you have any example? or what if I use anchor tags?